# Share extension registeredTypeIdentifiers

Tags: ios, swift

My share extension is supposed to handle Image, Video, File the same way, namely, just write it to shared container app group, but currently, i just do something like this:

```
   if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {  
  if let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {  
    if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeImage) {  
      itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeImage, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in  
        if let shareURL = url as? URL {  
          _ = self.openURL(URL(string: "cpc:/  
          if let image = NSData(contentsOf: shareURL) {  
            _ = self.writeSharedData(data: image, to: shareURL.lastPathComponent)  
          }  
          self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)  
        }  
      })  
    } else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypePDF) {  
      itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypePDF, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in  
        if let shareURL = url as? URL {  
          _ = self.openURL(URL(string: "cpc:/  
          if let pdf = NSData(contentsOf: shareURL) {  
            _ = self.writeSharedData(data: pdf, to: shareURL.lastPathComponent)  
          }  
          self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)  
        }  
      })  
    } else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeMovie) {  
      itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeMovie, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in  
        if let shareURL = url as? URL {  
          _ = self.openURL(URL(string: "cpc:/  
          if let pdf = NSData(contentsOf: shareURL) {  
            _ = self.writeSharedData(data: pdf, to: shareURL.lastPathComponent)  
          }  
          self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)  
        }  
      })  
    } else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeURL) {  
      itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeURL, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in  
        if let shareURL = url as? URL {  
          _ = self.openURL(URL(string: "cpc:/  
          self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)  
        }  
      })  
    } else {  
      extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Which handles types separately, thus very lengthy, so i dont know if any way i can check and handle forTypeIdentifier of Image, pdf, photo in just 1 if statement like this:

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeURL) {
```

}

Thanks,
Tuyen

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 condition since there is no property or method to get item provider type. But you can simplify the code by moving the common code into the separate method.

```
func loadItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider, contentType: NSString) {
  itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in  
    if let shareURL = url as? URL {  
      if (type == contentTypeURL) {
        //URL operation goes here
      } else {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: shareURL) {  
          self.writeSharedData(data: data, to: shareURL.lastPathComponent)  
        }  
      }
    } 
    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)   
  })
}
```

The call the method like following

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeImage) {  
  loadItem(itemProvider: itemProvider, contentType: contentTypeImage)

} else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypePDF) {  
  loadItem(itemProvider: itemProvider, contentType: contentTypePDF)

} else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeMovie) {  
  loadItem(itemProvider: itemProvider, contentType: contentTypeMovie)

} else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentTypeURL) {  
  loadItem(itemProvider: itemProvider, contentType: contentTypeURL)

} else {
  self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
}
```

Comment: It helps, Thanks, Surya!